# Topshelf multiple host

Tags: topshelf

Is there any way in topshelf to run multiple host in one executable?

```
// Create hosts
var h1 = HostFactory.New (...); var h2 = HostFactory.New (...)

// Start hosts
 in one application Runner.Run (h1, h2);
```

## Edit

Solved with threads. But not sure if it is safe...

```
new Thread (()=>Runner.Run (h1));    
new Thread (()=>Runner.Run (h2));
```

Comment: So this could cause a lot of a problems, I'm not sure the ServiceCoordinator is addressable safely like this, you might get cross talk between them. Also, this will have odd behaviour if you attempt to run it as a service and not just a console App. I wouldn't suggest this approach at all. If you want some more ideas, join our mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topshelf-discuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note*: This is only valid for pre-3.0 version of Topshelf. In 3.0 this was removed and is being replaced with other methods of hosting multiple services.

There is no way to run multiple hosts. Starting a host blocks execution, does a whole bunch of stuff. You can register multiple logical services in a single host though.

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/wiki/Creating-a-service

```
return (int)HostFactory.Run(x => {
  x.Service<Service1>({ ... });
  x.Service<Service2>({ ... ]);
});
```

All logical services run under a single AppDomain. This may or may not be an issue. If you need to host them in separate AppDomains, we started working on shelving. http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/shelving/ As a warning, if you're going to start multiple logical services with the same type, make sure they have unique names when configured.

Comment: As of 3.0, multiple services are not supported in this manner.

Comment: You say "in this manner". Is there any other way as of now ? I upgraded topshelf for trouble with Lognet 1.2.11 , only to see that this feature ( and the complete DSL for that matter) are gone or changed :s

Comment: How can we do this in TopShelf 3.0?

Answer (score 10):

From Topshelf [docs](http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html):

> You can only have ONE service! As of 3.x Topshelf the base product no
>   longer support hosting multiple services. This was done because the
>   code to implement was very brittle and hard to debug. We have opted
>   for a simpler and cleaner base product. This feature will most likely
>   come back in the form of an add on nuget.